# How to intercept websites with HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security)

Tags: xss, owasp, burp

When I am trying to intercept a website using Burp suite it gives error like [POTENTIAL SECURITY ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik1yu.png)

Comment: More details are missing. What exactly are you trying to do that triggers this error?
It could be due to a certificate error when you intercept with Burp suite and not add its certificate as a trusted root CA (use caution when doing so)

Comment: Yes you are right , it is due to certification error and now it is ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this article](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/questions/16358057-not-supporting-hsts) from PortSwigger, it will give you the capability to intercept HSTS WebSites.